403 Error When Importing Images to Google Vertex AI: Permissions Issue Despite Owner Role
I'm attempting to create a dataset of images using Google Vertex AI's inbuilt tool on the Google Cloud Platform. However, after selecting images to upload and pressing continue, I receive the following error:
Failed to start import operation.
Error message: "********@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist)."
Status: 403 Error code: 403
Tracking number: c5600366007031461

Context:

My account ********@gmail.com has the Owner and Editor roles for the project.
I have tried adding the Storage Object Creator role to my account, but the error persists.
I have also added the Storage Object Creator role to the relevant service accounts, including those used by Vertex AI, but without success.
I attempted to retrieve the IAM policy for the bucket using Cloud Shell but received another 403 error: Permission 'storage.buckets.getIamPolicy' denied.

Steps I've Taken:

Verified that my account has the Owner and Editor roles.
Ensured my 105 images to be uploaded are under 1.5MB in size.
Added the Storage Object Creator role to my account and the Vertex AI service account.
Ensured my project’s billing is active.
Tried using Google Cloud Shell to check bucket IAM policies but was denied access.
Deleted and created a new project to see if it was a one off.

Given these steps and persistent permission errors, what might be causing these 403 errors despite having the Owner role? Are there any additional configurations or settings I should verify to resolve this issue?
